# Creating new SettingsProperty "on the Fly"

Tags: c#, winforms, settings

I have a button a user can click. Depending on what button he clicks, the value, together with his ip should be saved in the `Properties.Settings.Default`, which may or may not exist already.

```
var property = new SettingsProperty("curVol" + ip);
property.DefaultValue = "DEFAULT";
Properties.Settings.Default.Properties.Add(property);
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();

/* Now Save to newly created Property */
Properties.Settings.Default["curVol" + ip] = ((XmlElement)xmlResponse.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild).InnerText;
/* NULL POINTER EXCEPTION */
```

How can I dynamically create a new Property and use it right afterwards?

Bonus: (I think I could figure it out myself though, if I have part one), how would I check if the property exists already? Check for `null`?

*Note:*

It does not have to be persistent after the form is closed, it is only for the current runtime.

**EDIT**

I think I may have thr wrong idea of how to achieve what I want: The program is able to reduce the volume of all my sonos speakers (in a listView) on click. When I click "make loud" then it should turn the volume to the level it was before, each of them may have a different level and there is an unknown number of speakers, so the "mute" function should somehow save the current level for each speaker before turning it down. Now that I think about it, a global varibale should do the trick?

**Own Answer**

Skipped the idea, used this instead:

```
var list = new List<Cfg>();

        foreach (ListViewItem item in sonosListExt1.Items)
        {

            list.Add(new Cfg { Ip = item.Text, Volume = "5" });
        }

        var gC = new GetConfig
        {
            Sonos = list
        };

        if (!Directory.Exists(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "cfg"))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "cfg");
        }
        File.WriteAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "cfg\\config.json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(gC));
```

with this class:

```
public class GetConfig
{
    public List<Cfg> Sonos { get; set; }
}

public class Cfg
{
    public string Ip { get; set; }
    public string Volume { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for the hints!

Comment: Have you tried a "try{} catch{}" statement for when the property doesn't exist, then creating it? what is contained in the default properties if you put a break point at the call to it?

Comment: Problem is the "creating it", not the checking that it does not exist. I know it doesnt. I can't see where I can get the contents of `Properties.Settings.Default` as having a breakpoint only shows this: http://imgur.com/a/VucUn

Comment: Instead of checking at the "Properties" level, move over to "Default" and see what is under it.

Comment: Neither Settings not Default can be inspected...

Comment: Adding properties to `Properties.Settings.Default` at run-time is meaningless. Can you say what you are trying to achieve? What's your goal?

Comment: @RezaAghaei is correct, the settings can be created at design time and can be changed between sessions. If you are attempting to store data to be held between sessions of the program you can access "Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData" and create a folder and file for your programs sole use.

Comment: Edited the question for clarification...